# Mocha/Chai expect an error when calling an async function

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

Im using mocha / chai to to do some testing.
The function is supposed to throw *new Error* if called with the same arguments.

**The function:**

Create a new user and save it do my database (mongoDB), if a user with the same discord id doesn't exist already. `fetchUser(disc_id)`searches for an existing user, by using `findOne()` from mongoose.

```
async function createUser(disc_id, moodleToken) {
    const profileData = await fetchUser(disc_id);
    if (profileData) {
        throw new Error("The account already exist in the database!");
    }
    
    const newUser = profileModel.create({
        discord_id: disc_id,
        moodle_token: moodleToken,
    }, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Document created!")
    })
    return newUser;
};
```

**fetchUser**

```
function fetchUser (disc_id) {
    return profileModel.findOne({ discord_id: disc_id });
}
```

**Testing**

Im using sinon to create the "test-database". The following test passes just fine

```
describe("Create user", function () {
        it("Should create a new user in database if the discord id is not in the database", async function () {
            const discord_id = "2341243451";
            const moodle_token = "fwefw89fwefHFEF0F90ls";
            
            sinon.stub(profileSchema, "findOne").returns(null);
            sinon.stub(profileSchema, "create").returns({
                discord_id, moodle_token
            });
            
            const returnedUser = await createUser(discord_id, moodle_token);
            
            expect(returnedUser.discord_id).to.equal(discord_id);
        })
```

This tests that it is possible to create and save a new user to my database, if no existing user has the same discord id.

If I want to test the opposite, to create a new user, but a current user already exists with the same id, it should throw the error: *"The account already exist in the database!"*

```
it("Should throw an error if there exists a user with that discord id", async () => {
            const discord_id = "2341243451";
            const moodle_token = "fwefw89fwefHFEF0F90ls";
            
            const fakeObject = {
                discord_id: discord_id,
                moodle_token: moodle_token
            };

            sinon.stub(profileSchema, "findOne").returns(fakeObject);
            sinon.stub(profileSchema, "create").returns({ discord_id, moodle_token })
```

I have tried to following without success:

```
            try {
                await createUser(discord_id, moodle_token);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                expect(err).to.equal("The account already exist in the database!");
            }
            
            expect(async function () { await createUser(discord_id, moodle_token); }).to.throw("The account already exist in the database!");
            expect(() => { createUser(discord_id, moodle_token)}).to.throw("The account already exist in the database!");
            rejects(async () => { await createUser(discord_id, moodle_token); })
```

How should i test such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem, i restructured my `createUser()` to this:

```
async function createUser(disc_id, moodleToken) {
    const profileData = await fetchUser(disc_id);
    if (profileData) {
        throw TypeError("The account already exist in the database!");
    }
    const newUser = new profileModel({
        discord_id: disc_id,
        moodle_token: moodleToken,
    })
    await newUser.save();
    return newUser;
}
```

The test passes if they are like this:

```
it("Should throw an error if there exists a user with that discord id", async () => {
            const discord_id = "2341243451";
            const moodle_token = "fwefw89fwefHFEF0F90ls";
            
            const fakeObject = {
                discord_id: "2341243451",
                moodle_token: "fwefw89fwefHFEF0F90ls"
            };

            sinon.stub(profileSchema, "findOne").returns(fakeObject);

            await createUser(discord_id, moodle_token).catch((error) => {
                expect(error.message).to.equal("The account already exist in the database!")
            })
```

Don't know if it is the right way to do it, but if i change `sinon.stub` to return `null` the test wont pass.

So i guess this is a way to handle it.